# Can I create a transparent background on a PictureBox in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, transparent, picturebox

I want to make the background of a `PictureBox` control transparent. In the `PictureBox` (rectangular shape), I placed an icon (circular in shape). I want to make the icon transparent so that the other portion underneath the icon is visible.

I have tried setting the `PictureBox.BackColor` property to "Transparent", but it doesn't work. I also tried to set it during runtime with the `Color.FromArgb` method, but it doesn't work either.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: What exactly is under the picturebox that you want to be visible?

Comment: try this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777203/animation-effects-in-winforms-c/4777987#4777987

Comment: This question gets asked a lot. See: [C#, how to make a picture background transparent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416934/c-how-to-make-a-picture-background-transparent) and [A PictureBox Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144371/a-picturebox-problem), among many *many* others.

Answer (score 4):

Setting `pictureBox.BackColor = Color.Transparent;` definitely should work.

Also verify if you are setting alpha channel of color when using `Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0)`; (this is a first parameter, zero means transparent color)

And, of course, make sure your icons have transparent background.

Comment: Setting the background color to transparent doesn't make these pixels transparent by default. It makes them have the background color of the parent control.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: sure, that's can be seen when 'transparent' control overlaps other control. That's because 'transparent' control asks parent control to draw it's background.

Comment: AFAIK, this will only work as per your example in comments to my answer: that is, when the parent controls don't use a solid color, i.e. an image.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointmen: This is not depends on what type of background used by parent control - whether it image or solid control, or userPaint - parent's background will be drawn on 'transparent' child.

Answer (score 2):

If using `WinForms` then Setting the background color to transparent won't work as transparency handling is not a cascading system - you can only (in most cases) set transparency (or rather the opacity) of a control overall using the `Opacity` property, however this will alter the alpha channel of the entire control display giving your images a see-througness.

One solution might be to set the background color of the `PictureBox` to be that of the control beneath it (the color of the form, for example). But this may not suffice in your situation.

Comment: In winforms Transparent won't work for Form background, but it works fine for controls.

Comment: And there is no PictureBox control in WPF. There is an Image control.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: Not all controls - try configuring background transparency for a `Label`, for instance (and evidently, for `PictureBox`. Granted I used `PictureBox` interchangeabley for both frameworks, will remove my references wo `WPF` anyway.

Comment: Label works fine. There are controls which do not allow transparent background (ListBox, TextBox, etc) but this is another story.

Comment: You have an example of `Label` and/or `PictureBox` _working fine_ in this manner? As a sanity check I just created a project to test and setting `Transparent` as the background for either simply leaves both controls with a `Control` (see: Gray) background.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: Here you are http://www.speedyshare.com/files/26839573/WindowsApplication5.zip

Comment: Ah, yes, it works if you don't have a solid color set as the background. You have an image set as the background, surely that's a special case?

Comment: For instance, if you remove your image and set the form's background color to `Red` and overlay two labels, you will see the top label's `Red` background over the one beneath. http://www.speedyshare.com/files/26839879/WindowsApplication5.zip

Comment: See my comment about 'transparency' in winforms. No matter what background of parent is - image or solid color - parent will draw it on child control. But parent do not know anything about overlaying. So you get this behavior. There are some ways to achieve overlaying transparency (e.g. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943454). But in my life default 'transparency' always was enough to use.

Comment: Well, it's pretty flawed; even in your original example, if you move the `Label` over the little icon `PictureBox` then you will see the fail.

Comment: 1) I described the reason of this behavior (because Form is the parent of Label); 2) Question was about transparent pictureBox, not about transparency implementation in Winforms; 3) If you want label over picture - use control, which could be parent to the label (e.g. Panel)

Answer (score 0):

hi you must set the icon on the other portion underneath the icon by using this

icon_pictureBox_name.Controls.Add(other_portion_picturBox_name);

and after that you can set the PictureBox.BackColor property to "Transparent" and it will work ;)